# One Angular directive using another

Tags: angularjs

I have two directives, one shows a little box around a name (it takes the ID, asks the backend what the actual name is), the second one draws a beutiful card (OK card). If I use the card as html it works a charm, but as a directive, the first "box" directive does not work. OK, I can move the functionality and the API request into the second directive, but that seems wrong, I would also need to use promise I recon.

The other option is to compile, but I am not certain what to compile and how. Preferably I want (or think I want) the  to be added to the DOM, so they call the skillBox directive and get their response as and when.

The first directive (skillBox)

```
knowledge.directive('skillBox', function(cvFactory){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { skill: '='},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("Got called")
            scope.$watch('skill', function(skill) {
                cvFactory.getNameById(skill.skill, function(idName){
                    console.log("Got name " + idName)
                    var color;
                    if ( skill.score > 79) {
                        color = "green";
                    } else if ( skill.score > 49 ) {
                        color = "yellow";
                    } else {
                        color = "grey"
                    }
                    element.addClass('skillbox')
                    element.css("background-color",color);
                    element.html(idName);
                    //return idName
                });


                //'<span class="skillbox" style="background-color: ' + color + '">' + idName + '</span>'
            })
            scope.$watch('skill.score', function(newScore){
                console.log("newscore"+ newScore);
                var color;
                if ( newScore > 79) {
                    color = "green";
                } else if ( newScore > 49 ) {
                    color = "yellow";
                } else {
                    color = "grey"
                }
                element.css("background-color",color);
                //var cuHtml = element.html();

                //var skillbox = element[0].getElementsByClassName('skillbox');

                //element.html('<span class="skillbox" style="background-color: ' + color + '">' + idName + '</span>');
            })
            //scope.name = myData.name;
        }
    }
})
```

The second one (the one that I want to call the first one)

```
knowledge.directive('showCvCard', function(cvFactory){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { minimized: '=',
                cv: '='},
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            var minimizedInt = true;
            console.log("Got called")
            $scope.$watch('minimized', function(newValue){
                console.log("New minimized value " + newValue)
                minimizedInt = newValue
            })
            $scope.$watch('cv', function(newValue) {
                //console.log("minimized is now " + newValue.minimized)
                var carddata;
                carddata='<md-card class="md-padding"">'
                carddata=carddata + '<md-card-title layout="row">'
                carddata=carddata + '<md-card-title-media layout="column" layout-align="top end">'
                carddata=carddata + '<div class="md-media-md card-media"><img src="'+newValue.profileImg.dataURL+'" type="" class="profile-pic" alt="Profile view"></div>'
                carddata=carddata + '</md-card-title-media>'
                carddata=carddata + '<md-card-title-text layout="column">'
                //carddata=carddata + '<span class="md-headline">Name: '+ newValue.firstName+ ' '+ newValue.familyName+'</span>'
                carddata=carddata + '<span class="md-subhead">'+newValue.jobTitle+' - Available - '+ newValue.avail+'</span>'
                carddata=carddata + '<p class="md-body-1">'+ newValue.summary+'</p>'
                carddata=carddata + '<p class="md-body-1">'
                for (var i in newValue._skillSet){
                    var color;
                    var score = newValue._skillSet[i].score
                    if ( score > 79) {
                        color = "green";
                    } else if ( score > 49 ) {
                        color = "yellow";
                    } else {
                        color = "grey"
                    }
                    cvFactory.getNameById(newValue._skillSet[i].skill, function(idName) {
                        console.log('<span class="skillbox" style="background-color:' + color + '">' + idName +'<span>')
                        carddata = carddata + '<span class="skillbox" style="background-color:' + color + '">' +  idName+'<span>'
                    })
                }
                //carddata=carddata + '<p class="md-body-1"> <skill-box skill="skill" ng-repeat="skill in '+ newValue.CV._skillSet+'"></skill-box></p><hr>'
                carddata=carddata + '</md-card-title-text>'
                carddata=carddata + '</md-card-title>'
                carddata=carddata + '<md-card-content style="overflow-y: scroll">'
                //carddata=carddata + '<p class="md-body-1"> <skill-box skill="skill" ng-repeat="skill in iAm.CV._skillSet"></skill-box></p><hr>'
                carddata=carddata + '<p class="md-body-1">{{iAm.CV.CV}}</p>'
                carddata=carddata + '</md-card-content>'
                carddata=carddata + '</md-card>'
                element.html(carddata);
            })

            $scope.minimize = function(){
                if ( $scope.minimized === true ) {
                    $scope.minimized = false;
                } else {
                    $scope.minimized = true;
                }
            }

        }
    }
})
```

Can I somehow just throw carddata at the compiler (note, currently it kind of works, but because of the API, the correct HTML is generated, but only after the rest of carddata has already been sent to the DOM, hence the promise)

==== Simple solution ====

Use template and life is good, seems like template is compiled:
knowledge.directive('testCv', function(cvFactory){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {minimized: '=',
        cv: '='},
        template: ''+
            ''+
            ''+
            ''+
            ''+
            ''+
            'Name: {{ cv.firstName }}'+
            '{{cv.CV.jobTitle}} - Available - {{cv.CV.avail}}'+
            '{{cv.CV.summary}}

'+
            ''+
            ''+
            ''+
            '{{cv.CV.CV}}'+
            ''+
            ''
    }
})

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure if I understood your question, but you can 'include' another directive as a dependency in a directive.

Here is a little example:

The view:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <country>
    <state> 
      <city>

      </city>
    </state>
  </country>
</div>
```

Initial setup:

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.directive("country", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    controller: function () {
      this.makeAnnouncement = function (message) { 
        console.log("Country says: " + message);
      };
    }
  };
});
app.directive("state", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E"
  };
});
app.directive("city", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    require: "^country",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, countryCtrl) {
      countryCtrl.makeAnnouncement("This city rocks");
    }
  };
});
```

Here, we can inject the country directive controller into the linking function of the city directive. This is accomplished by matching the require naming scheme to the parent directive name. With this, the controller of the parent directive is available for use in the child directive. This ‘inheritance’ of the controller works invariant of ancestral distance.

This controller inheritance is not limited to a single controller instance:

```
});
app.directive("state", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    controller: function () {
      this.makeLaw = function (law) {
        console.log("Law: " + law);
      };
    }
  };
});
app.directive("city", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    require: ["^country","^state"],
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
      ctrls[0].makeAnnouncement("This city rocks");
      ctrls[1].makeLaw("Jump higher");
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: OK, I might be going about this the wrong way. Problem is that the first directive (skillBox) does not have a controller, or at least I don't think so, it just uses link. So if I call it in the html file, I just add <skill-box> and magically the link stuff happens. Now (I changed the link in the cvcard) just outputs <skill-box skill=[Object Object]></skill-box>, but it is never compiled, so the directive skill-box is never called. Can I use the require on the directive rather than the controller. Or am I missing how it works completely (quite possible :) )

Comment: I may have shot my self in the foot here:). Or maybe I am missing something:) So the first one uses link to return (write to element) a little box, what I want now is the second one to create the "hooks" <skill-box skill=.... > which the first one then picks up and translates. I could change it so that the first one calls the second one, actually, maybe that is how I have to do it, let the first one be two, one link and one controller which works together, than the second one only uses the controller. (thinking on the fly here)

Comment: OK, seems like there is a model that is about a BILLION times easier, and along your model I think, just add everything as a template, and that is fully compiled, all the stuff about DOM sorts it self out. And while its not a 100% match to your response, you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

========== THIS MIGHT BE OF INTEREST JUST AS A THEORETICAL EXCERSIZE =======
== Found a much simpler way of doing it using template and controller ==

OK, I found one way of doing it, it isn't pretty, but works quite well for me as I wanted to be able to change it based on some data from ngModel at a later date. So the trick is to get the link to first return the structure, with all bits but leave a span with an id which it can refer to later, in my case I used "skillSpan" `carddata=carddata + '<md-card-content><span id="skillSpan"></span></md-card-content>'`. So the scope watch for cv  looks like this

```
$scope.$watch('cv', function(newValue) {
            //console.log("minimized is now " + newValue.minimized)
            var carddata;
            carddata='<md-card class="md-padding"">'
            carddata=carddata + '<md-card-title layout="row">'
            carddata=carddata + '<md-card-title-media layout="column" layout-align="top end">'
            carddata=carddata + '<div class="md-media-md card-media"><img src="'+newValue.profileImg.dataURL+'" type="" class="profile-pic" alt="Profile view"></div>'
            carddata=carddata + '</md-card-title-media>'
            carddata=carddata + '<md-card-title-text layout="column">'
            //carddata=carddata + '<span class="md-headline">Name: '+ newValue.firstName+ ' '+ newValue.familyName+'</span>'
            carddata=carddata + '<span class="md-subhead">'+newValue.jobTitle+' - Available - '+ newValue.avail.toLocaleDateString()+'</span>'
            carddata=carddata + '<p class="md-body-1">'+ newValue.summary+'</p>'
            //carddata=carddata + '<p class="md-body-1">'

            //for (var i in newValue._skillSet) {
            //    carddata = carddata +'<skill-box skill="' + newValue._skillSet[i] + '"></skill-box>'
            //}
            carddata=carddata + '</md-card-title-text>'
            carddata=carddata + '</md-card-title>'
            carddata=carddata + '<md-card-content><span id="skillSpan"></span></md-card-content>'
            carddata=carddata + '<md-card-content style="overflow-y: scroll">'
            //carddata=carddata + '<p class="md-body-1"> <skill-box skill="skill" ng-repeat="skill in iAm.CV._skillSet"></skill-box></p><hr>'
            carddata=carddata + '<p class="md-body-1">'+newValue.CV+'</p>'
            carddata=carddata + '</md-card-content>'
            carddata=carddata + '</md-card>'
            element.html(carddata);
            updateSkillBox(newValue._skillSet)
        })
```

Once this is done, it calls a function called updateSkillBox which picks up the id updateSkillBox then it writes to the id manually.

```
    function updateSkillBox(skillSet, filter){
        var skillSpan = angular.element(document.querySelector('#skillSpan'))
        skillSpan.html(''); //This resets it, because we want to
        //console.log(skillSet[i].score)
        for (var i in skillSet) {
            console.log(skillSet[i].score)
            var color;
            var score = skillSet[i].score
            if (score > 79) {
                color = "green";
            } else if (score > 49) {
                color = "yellow";
            } else {
                color = "grey"
            }
            cvFactory.getNameByIdnColor(skillSet[i].skill, color, function (idName, idColor) {
                //console.log('<span class="skillbox" style="background-color:' + color + '">' + idName + '<span>')
                skillSpan.append('<span class="skillbox" style="background-color:' + idColor + '">' + idName + '<span>')
            })
        }
    }
```

I should add that currently this option may only work once on a page, as I am looking for ID, which could be repeated, but that is next step, set ID to a value that is unique